# How to multiply value from previous command to some constant?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation, splunk-formula

I am doing a query such that it will take the total count of the a value and then multiply it by some constant. For example :

```
source="test.csv"  sourcetype="csv" | stats count(adId)
```

I want to multiply the result returned by the count by 0.5. Suppose if the output by `stats count` is 124 I want to multiply it by 0.5 and report the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `eval`.  First have `stats` put its result in a better-named field.  I also use `exact` for better precision and `round` to control the number of decimal places.

```
source="test.csv"  sourcetype="csv" 
| stats count(adId) as interim 
| eval output = round(exact(interim * 0.5), 3)
```

You could do it without an interim field, if you wish.

```
source="test.csv"  sourcetype="csv" 
| stats count(adId) as output
| eval output = round(exact(output * 0.5), 3)
```